# How to troubleshoot problems when tomcat servlet connects to mysql

Tags: mysql, tomcat, servlets, jdbc

Tomcat servlet gets connection to mysql with getConnection(). Just fetch data from db test table shop.Connection to mysql is successful, but browser doesn't still show any data from backend. JavaScript shows request.status is 200 and request.readyState is 2 or 3. How can I find the problem? I even don't see any exceptions in tomcat log file.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("ok");

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "***");
            Statement statementQuery = connection.createStatement();

            ResultSet set = statementQuery.executeQuery("select * from shop");

            // connection.commit();  Error appears here(should be commented): 
            out.println("<div>");
            while (set.next()) {
                out.println("ok");
                out.println(set.getInt(1) + " ");
                out.println(set.getString(2) + " ");
                out.println(set.getDouble(3));          
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.println("</div>");

        out.flush();
        out.close();    
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws IOException, ServletException {
        doGet(request, response);
}
```

**EDIT**:
connection.commit() is wrong. Comment that line and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Oracle driver to Mysql driver

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

SQL statements are executed sequentially. Change the order of execution to:

```
int ret = statement.executeUpdate("insert into shop values  (53, 'fjd', 43.2)"); 
ResultSet s1 = statement.executeQuery("select * from shop");
```

Execute also a commit on the connection

```
connection.commit();
```

And add a `finally` to close `statement` and `connection`

```
}finally{
    statement.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

Comment: I think it's the matter of mysql connection, instead of execution order. Because the table doesn't change in db after sql staement insert.

Comment: You are using the oracle driver. Then use `connection.commit();`

Comment: You are reusing `statement`. The update will close the opened cursor over the query. Reorder it, or use a new statement

Comment: Servlet still can't update db table because table doesn't change.  I put mysql-connector.jar in tomcat/lib. Nothing else. Is there other work needed?

Comment: Is web.xml necessary for servelt connecting to mysql?

Comment: You do not have to configure anything for mysql in `web.xml`. Are you sure your code is being executed and not is printing an exception? Ensure this statement `insert into shop values  (53, 'fjd', 43.2)`really inserts a record. For example using MySQL Workbench

Comment: Now insert into table works because of mysql-connector.jar. But the select statement doesn't return data to browser. JavaScript shows request satus is 200, and request redayState is 2 or 3. How can I find the problem?

Comment: Debug the code to detect the problem. response will allways be 200 because you are catching all exceptions. Try to return a different message if it is reached the exception case. Have you reordered the statements?

Comment: Yes, I delete the insert statement because it works. I just added it for connection debug. All I need to do is just to fetch data by select and send it to foreend.Thanks for your time. But I can't accept your answer because I haven't successfully sent data back.

Comment: Can you include the current version of your code? Have you printed the log messages to know if the code is retrieving results or is there an exception ?. If you use for example `e.printStackTrace ()`, the trace will be displayed in the tomcat logs

Comment: I have updated the question. Can I delete the old version to make the question clearly?

Comment: `Connection.commit` is not needed because you are not updating data. It  can close the ResultSet objects that have been created during the current transaction. Remove it.

Comment: The question is yours, so update it if you consider it is better. StackOverflow has version control

Comment: I have updated. Because Your answer is related to the original code, so I need to ask you firstly.